# Bootstrap navbar with pills and Angular

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular8

I am working with the following example:

[Routing example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular)

Where in app.component.html I am modifying:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
```

to

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
```

So, now tabs look like pills.

Then I copied navbar into another example:

[Testing example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-wtpacb)

And the navbar doesn't look the same as in the original example. Both examples are running the same Bootstrap version. While the second example doesn't include the  router I am not sure if it makes any difference.

Can somebody please help understand what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you install bootstrap,jQuery etc.. but not affected into your app so, add reference of css & js into "Angular.json" -> Build Array -> as below:

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
 "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
             "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
```

Comment: I added both to the Build Array, and it looks like this: HomeServersUsers

Comment: The only difference I see is that routing example uses Angular 4 and testing example uses Angular 8.

Comment: i am not confirm about misbehave but i think something went wrong with bootstrap or jquery.

Comment: I see what the problem is. The routing example uses Bootstrap3 :((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Answer (score 0):

Try including something like this in your index.html

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

And you need a diffrent structure of your navbar. `nav-item` and `nav-link` are important

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">Second</a></li>
</ul>
```

Maybe thats it

Comment: I will try, but routing example doesn't have <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> in its index.html. And why do I need a different structure if they both us same resources?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't in the example but I think it's a safe way to do it. The structure with ```nav-item``` and ```nav-link``` is pretty standard, so the styling looks like expected ;)

Comment: I did it, did not help.

Comment: Looks like this:    Home   Second. Selection doesn't work.